# Determine whether the given points are limit points of the given set

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $P = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 0 \le x^2 < 1, 2 < y \le 4 \}$ and $S = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 1\le x \le 3, y = 2 \}$.

1. Are $(0,3)$ and $(0,4)$ be the limit points of $P$?
2. Are all points of $S \cup P$ be the limit points of $S \cup P$?

**Attempt:**
For 1, I tried on $(0,3)$ first like this.

Let $r > 0 $. To check: $(0,3)$ is a limit point of $P$. In other words, $B((0,3),r) \cap P \setminus \{(0,3) \} \ne \emptyset$.

Let $(x,y) \in B((0,3),r) \setminus \{(0,3)\}$. Then, we have
\begin{align*}
x^2 + (y-3)^2 < r^2 \\
x^2 < r^2 \ \wedge (y-3)^2 < r^2 \\
-r < x < r \ \wedge 3-r < y < 3+r
\end{align*}
Consider the interval $(3,3+r)$. We take a smallest $y$ in $(3,3+r)$, say $y = 3 + \frac{r}{3}$.
Then, we have
\begin{align*}
x^2 + ((3 + \frac{r}{3}) - 3)^2 = \frac{r^2}{9} < r^2
\end{align*}
which means that $(0,3+\frac{r}{3}) \in B((0,3),r) \setminus \{(0,3) \}$. On the other hand, it's clear that $(0,3+\frac{r}{3}) \in P$. Hence, we have $B((0,3),r) \cap P \setminus \{(0,3)\} = \{(0,3+\frac{r}{3}) \} \ne \emptyset$. Therefore, $(0,3)$ is a limit point of $P$.

Is it true? If yes, then the analog could be used on $(0,4)$.

For 2, I'm not sure that the answer is true since there exists point that would be outside of $S \cup P$. Here's what I tried.

I'm considering the point $(3,2) \in S \cup P$ and take $r = 1 > 0$.

To show: $B((3,2), 1) \cap (S \cup P) \setminus \{(3,2) \} = \emptyset$.
Let $(x,y) \in B((3,2),1) \setminus \{(3,2)\}$. Then, we have
\begin{align*}
(x-3)^2 + (y-2)^2 < 1 \\
-1 < x-3 < 1 \ \wedge -1 < y-2 < 1 \\
2 < x < 4 \ \wedge 1 < y < 3.
\end{align*}
But, the point $(3.5, 2) \notin S \cup P$. Hence, we have
$B((3,2),1) \cap (S \cup P) \setminus \{(3,2)\} = \emptyset$.

Am I true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\lambda$ is a limit point of a set $S$ is also equivalent to the fact there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \setminus \{\lambda\}$ such that $x_n \to \lambda.$ This is usually easier to check than the exact definition of $S'$ (they are in fact equivalent). For example, you might have noticed that $((\frac1n, 3 + \frac1n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq P \setminus \{(0, 3)\}$ and the limit of this sequence is of course equal to $(0, 3),$ so this is a limit point indeed. Analogously one shows that $(0, 4) \in P'.$

Your reasoning of the second part is not entirely sound. $(3, 2) \in (S \cup P)'$ because $((3 - \frac1n, 2))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (S \cup P) \setminus\{(3, 2)\}.$ It is a general fact (and also not hard to prove) that the closure of a set is the union of its limit and isolated points (disjoint union, of course). Note that $S$ is closed and has no isolated points. Therefore, any point of $S$ is a limit point of $S,$ so it is also a limit point of $S \cup P.$ The closure of $P$ is $\overline{P} = [-1, 1] \times [2, 4]$ and it clearly has no isolated points, so $P \subseteq \overline{P} = P',$ hence any point in $P$ is a limit point of $P,$ so also a limit point of $S \cup P.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: what about my answer for $(0,3)$? Is it not true?

Comment: any approach that not using sequence, for example, as mine above?

Comment: Anw, I understood on your answer above. But, I only ask, why mine above was not true for the $(0,3)$?

Comment: First of all, the methods are equivalent. The ball definition for the limit points of a set $S$ says that $p$ is a limit point of $S$ if for all $r > 0,$ the intersection $B(p, r) \cap S \setminus \{p\}$ is nonempty. Letting $r > 0,$ you retrieve the sequence definition. Conversely, having a sequence such as above ($(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq S \setminus \{p\},$ $x_n \to p$), you deduce that $B(p, r) \cap S \setminus \{p\}$ is nontrivial for all $r > 0$ such that there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r > \Vert x_n - p \Vert,$ so it is true for all $r > 0$ since $x_n \to p.$

Comment: That being said, it really does not matter which of the definitions you use, because you can always easily recover the other one.

Comment: Secondly, your proof of the fact that $(0, 3) \in P',$ while very convoluted and hard to read at times, is correct and indeed the same argument works for $(0, 4).$ Your idea of proof for $(3, 2)$ doesn't work because I think you are confusing some notions. When you write out what being in that ball means, the last line is not equivalent to being in the ball unless you are talking about the ball in the $\infty-$norm, which I'm pretty sure you're not since on the second line you talk about the ball in the $2-$norm yourself.

Comment: You then go on to say "but $(3.5, 2) \not\in S \cup P.$ This is correct, so what? Does it mean that there are no points in $(S \cup P) \cap B((3, 2)) \setminus \{(3, 2)\}?$ Not at all! In fact, for all $r > 0,$ $(\max\{1, 3 - r\}, 2) \in (B((3, 2), r) \cap (S \cup P)) \setminus \{(3, 2)\},$ so there you go, this shows once again that $(3, 2)$ is a limit point. Please don't confuse necessity and sufficiency and make sure you have a solid grasp on the basic concepts.

Comment: great explaining. thanks sir!

Comment: how to prove the second with your idea, like for all $r > 0$, $(\max\{... \} , ...) \in ...$?
i mean, what should I take? a point $(x,y)$? if yes, then I use $(\max\{1,x-r\}, y) \in ...$?

Comment: Let $(x,y) \in S \cup P$. To show: $(x,y)$ is a limit point. Let $r>0$. Then, we have $(\max\{1,x-r \}, y) \in B((x,y),r) \cap (S \cup P) \setminus \{(x,y) \}$. Hence, $B((x,y),r) \cap (S \cup P) \setminus \{(x,y) \} \ne \emptyset$. Therefore, $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $S \cup P$. Like this?